# How we can add a double quotes to list of arguments from command line to python code

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Can anyone please help me how to add double quotes to multiple arguments passed from a CLI to python code

ASK :

I am passing a list of argument to a single parameter and at the python code I need to add "" double quotes to all the value passed from the arguments

At the CLI I am passing, for e.g. value1=[a,b,c,d]

At the python code I am using below code to get all the parameter of the value1

value1=[varibaleName.args.value1]

But while passing/interpreting these values I need to add a double quotes to all the value lets say for e.g. it should be treated like below

```
value1=["a","b","c","d"]
```

So when I pass the argument at CLI, it should be interpreted as in double quotes while assigning those values to variable/list.

Please let me know if the ask in unclear to you and need your help ! Appreciate for fast response

Need a code how to add double quotes to all value passed to a list argument from CLI

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also don't forget how to create a [mre] or how to [edit] your questions. Lastly please tell us *exactly* what you're doing (when you invoke the Python script, what are you really passing for arguments? Please copy-paste actual command and script invocation).

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're asking  Remember that `{"a","b","c","d"]` is just the REPRESENTATION of a simple list of strings.  Each string in that list only contains one character.  The string does not contain double quotes, although double quotes are used when printing the values.  You would not add quotes to the values you got from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes are ignored by the interpreter. You can encase the string in single quotes.
Using test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

And running in the terminal as follows:

```
python args.py '"a"' '"b"' '"c"'
```

gives output with double quotes as follows:

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['args.py', '"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
```

You can also escape the double-quotes as follows

```
python args.py \"a\" \"b\" \"c\"
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['args.py', '"a"', '"b"', '"c"']
```